# TensorFlow Probability MCMC with Bernoulli distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use TensorFlow Probability to implement Markov Chain Monte Carlo with sampling from a Bernoulli distribution. 
However, my attempts are showing results not consistent with what I would expect from a Bernoulli distribution.

I modified the example given in the documentation of tfp.mcmc.sample_chain (sampling from a diagonal-variance Gaussian) [example here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/mcmc/sample_chain) to draw from a Bernoulli distribution. Since the Bernoulli distribution is discrete, I used the RandomWalkMetropolis transition kernel instead of the
Hamiltonian Monte Carlo kernel, which I expect would not work since it computes a gradient.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

def make_likelihood(event_prob):
    return tfd.Bernoulli(probs=event_prob,dtype=tf.float32)


dims=1
event_prob = 0.3
num_results = 30000
likelihood = make_likelihood(event_prob)


states, kernel_results = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_results=num_results,
    current_state=tf.zeros(dims),
    kernel = tfp.mcmc.RandomWalkMetropolis(
              target_log_prob_fn=likelihood.log_prob,
              new_state_fn=tfp.mcmc.random_walk_normal_fn(scale=1.0),
              seed=124
             ),
    num_burnin_steps=5000)

chain_vals = states

# Compute sample stats.
sample_mean = tf.reduce_mean(states, axis=0)
sample_var = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.squared_difference(states, sample_mean),
    axis=0)

#initialize the variable
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op) 
    [sample_mean_, sample_var_, chain_vals_] = sess.run([sample_mean,sample_var,chain_vals])

chain_samples = (chain_vals_[:] )   
print ('Sample mean = {}'.format(sample_mean_))
print ('Sample var = {}'.format(sample_var_))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig.set_size_inches(12, 10)

axes[0].plot(chain_samples[:])
axes[0].title.set_text("values sample chain tfd.Bernoulli")
sns.kdeplot(chain_samples[:,0], ax=axes[1], shade=True)
axes[1].title.set_text("chain tfd.Bernoulli distribution")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I expected to see values for the states of the Markov chain in the interval [0,1].

The result for the Markov chain values does not look like what is expected for a Bernoulli distribution, nor does the KDE plot, as shown
in this figure:

[image]

Do I have a conceptual flaw with my example, or mistake in using the TensorFlow Probability API ?

Or is there possibly an issue with the TF.Probability implementation of Markov Chain Monte Carlo 
using a discrete distribution such as the  Bernoulli distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the source of your confusing experience is that you are still using a continuous proposal distribution in the `RandomWalkMetropolis` transition.  The convention in TensorFlow Probability for integer distributions (including `Bernoulli`) is to implement a continuous relaxation by default.  IIRC, for Bernoulli, that's `pdf(x) ~ p ** x * (1 - p) ** (1 - x)`; once `x` becomes negative, this will steadily drive your random walk Markov chain toward `-inf`, as you observe.

Several things you can do about this:

1. Use pass `validate_args=True` to the `Bernoulli` constructor.  This will crash if `x` is not 0 or 1, helping you detect the issue (but don't if you want non-integer results in the interval [0, 1]).
2. Use a different proposal function, such as an independent uniform between 0 and 1.  Writing your own is not very hard---here's literally the code of the Gaussian drift proposal function you were using: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/python/mcmc/random_walk_metropolis.py#L97-L107.  Note that the proposal needs to be symmetric to work correctly with `RandomWalkMetropolis`.
3. Use a different MCMC transition operator altogether.

I also filed a ticket about making a TransitionKernel for independence proposals (such as what I imagine you might need): https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/218